# Adding single quotes specifically in a text file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of Raw data which i need to insert into database, but the thing is i need to add single quotes in bulk for one of the data column for the query purpose. I was wondering is there a way to do so, currently i only know excel VBA can add in the single quotes, but i need some time to figure out how to do this. Maybe there are other simple ways to do this? I need an advice regarding this. I will attach an image to illustrate the problem i am facing, i believe others might face the same problem like i do. Thank you.

[image: Illustration about the problem]

Comment: Can you post the associated code?

Comment: Exactly why do you need the single quote?

Comment: i don't have any codes with me currently, these are all raw backup data file from mysql, currently i need to figure out how to add in '' in bulk for my current situation.

Comment: Single quote so that i can add in the date in string format due to old database design

Comment: @ThomasInzina did you meant the text file i shown in image format? I mean you want the whole text file?

Comment: Just import the file into Excel, and specify the format of that field as being text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open txt file in Excel
2. Split columns(if necessary)
3. Using function ="""&E1&""" then fill down